# What is the missing code is my sql query

Tags: mysql, netbeans-7

Hi I have a program where I am creating an edit button, when I paste this code:

```
String sql="update Items set Item_ID='"+val1+"' ,Item_Name='"+val2+"' ,Price='"+val3+"' ,Quantity='"+val4+"' ,Type='"+val5+"' ,Expiry_Date='"+val6"' ,Brand='"+val7+"' ,Origin='"+val8+"' ,Perishable='"+val9+"' ,Manufacturer='"+val10+"' ";
```

its says that ';' is expected, but I already have it in the end.

please help! I am using netbeans and mysql

Comment: Not an answer to your original question, but you might want to construct your query in a different way (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: You dont have it at the end. that ; you have is for java. You should have another ; inbetween the "" to complete the SQL query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `+` after `val6`:

```
String sql="update Items set Item_ID='"+val1+"', Item_Name='"+val2+"',
  Price='"+val3+"', Quantity='"+val4+"', Type='"+val5+"', Expiry_Date='"+val6+"',
  Brand='"+val7+"', Origin='"+val8+"', Perishable='"+val9+"',
  Manufacturer='"+val10+"' ";
```

Comment: Oh yes you are right, looks like I need to use sunglasses now. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with netbeans syntax, but usually an error like that means somewhere in that one line it was expecting it to end but instead it saw continued statements.  In this case, you are missing a `+` in between val6 and the next string.